# Downloading attachment to each folder which name is the id of the attachment crm2011

Tags: c#, dynamics-crm-2011, dynamics-crm, crm

I am creating a console app that downloads attachments (annotation) for each entity.The idea is to create a primary folder with the entity name,sub folders of the entity folder named with the object id of the annotation, and in each sub folder will be the files corresponding the with the id of the folder.Here is my code till now:

```
string filepath = "C:\\";
String fetchXmlNote = "<fetch mapping='logical' count='20'>";
fetchXmlNote += "<entity name='annotation'>";
fetchXmlNote += "<attribute name='filename'/>";
fetchXmlNote += "<attribute name='documentbody'/>";
fetchXmlNote += "<attribute name='mimetype'/>";
fetchXmlNote += "<attribute name='objectid'/>";
fetchXmlNote += "<link-entity name='" +EntityName+ "' from='" + EntityName + "id' to='objectid'>";
fetchXmlNote += "</link-entity>";
fetchXmlNote += "</entity>";
fetchXmlNote += "</fetch>";

Microsoft.Xrm.Sdk.EntityCollection result = service.RetrieveMultiple(new FetchExpression(fetchXmlNote));
if (result != null)
{
    FilePath = FilePath + EntityName + "\\";

    foreach (Entity e in result.Entities)
    {
        Directory.CreateDirectory(FilePath + e.GetAttributeValue<EntityReference>("objectid").Id.ToString());
        if (!String.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(e.Attributes["documentbody"].ToString()))
        {
            byte[] data = Convert.FromBase64String(e.Attributes["documentbody"].ToString());

            File.WriteAllBytes(FilePath + e.Attributes["filename"].ToString(), data);
        }
```

Till now i have made the fetch xml for downloading the files, and i have created the folder for each objectid, but i need to put each file in the corresponding folder with the corresponding id.
Note that a check for duplicate is needed.
Any help is appreciated.

Comment: Not sure what you're asking. You already have the code to create a directory (`Directory.CreateDirectory`) and you already have the `objectid`. What problem are you having?

Answer (score 0):

try checking for each `file/folder` if it already exists

```
using System.IO;


if (result != null)
{
FilePath = FilePath + EntityName;
if(CheckIfFolderExists(FilePath + EntityName)==false) //Check primary folder, if do not exists create one
{
    Directory.CreateDirectory(FilePath + EntityName); //Create primary folder
}
FilePath+= "\\"; 
foreach (Entity e in result.Entities)
{  
    if(CheckIfFolderExists(FilePath + e.GetAttributeValue<EntityReference>("objectid").Id.ToString()))==false) //Check subfolder, if do not exists create one
    {
     Directory.CreateDirectory(FilePath + e.GetAttributeValue<EntityReference>("objectid").Id.ToString()); //Create subfolder inside primary folder
    }
//Also check here, if file with the same name already exists, if not create one
    if (!String.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(e.Attributes["documentbody"].ToString()) && !File.Exists(FilePath + e.Attributes["filename"].ToString()))
    {
        byte[] data = Convert.FromBase64String(e.Attributes["documentbody"].ToString());
        File.WriteAllBytes(FilePath + e.Attributes["filename"].ToString(), data);
    }
}
}
public static bool CheckIfFolderExists(string path)
{
 return Directory.Exists(path);
}
```